# How to get IMG tag code from HTML document?

Tags: php, html-parsing

how I get the `img` code from a text?
Now I get the code and URL if the tag looks like: `text text <img src = "image.gif" />`, but if the code is `<img src = "image.gif" target = _blank />`, then I get the URL: `"image.gif" target = _blank`.

So, how correctly find `img` full code and URL?

Thanks

```
preg_match_all('/\<img src = (.*?)\/>/', $input, $all_img);
```

Comment: input example would be nice ...

Comment: *(related)* [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don’t try to parse HTML with regular expressions; use an HTML parser like [PHP’s DOM library](http://php.net/dom) or the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead (see Gordon’s comment for further alternatives).

Here’s an example with the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser:

```
$html = str_get_html('…');
foreach ($html->find('img[src]') as $img) {
    echo $img->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Comment: @user319854: Use the `__toString` method: `$img->__toString()`.