# Regular expression match all image URLs

Tags: php, regex, image, preg-match-all

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get IMG tag code from HTML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838887/get-img-code-and-link-from-text)

I need help to make **preg_match_all()** for every image URL on random page.
As far I do this

```
preg_match_all('/img[\d\D]+?src\=(\'|\")([\d\D]+?)(\'|\")/i', $page, $matches);
```

But won't work for every page.
Must match all possible image closed in **img src** also ones that doesn't look like images.
thank you

Comment: Regex is not the right tool here. Have a look at a HTML parser.

Comment: Nope, what do you mean ? Can you give me link or something?     But will be nice if you help me with the regex - cause It take me lot of time and I want to see it done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the html DOM parser -> http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

all you need to do then is use this code:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't need to include all that code at the moment - script is too simple for that, but maybe will be helpful later.

Comment: 10x again - that parser is very cewl

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).